# Pass multiple user inputs from python into SQL query

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am working on a project that asks me to prompt the user to enter some ids in order to retrieve relevant data from database using SQL developer.

I knew how to just take one piece of user input and put it into one SQL query but struggle to tackle multiple user inputs.

For example, I can prompt the user to enter share_id for me to search for corresponding trade like this:

```
connection = cx_Oracle.connect("hr", "oracle", "localhost/orcl")
cursor = connection.cursor()

share_id_val = input("Enter share id to search: ")
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM trades WHERE share_id = :share_id", share_id = share_id_val)
```

But if the user may enter **one or more of [share_id, broker_id, date_range]**, then I can only think of building 6 SQL queries, one for each case (that's very inefficient for sure).

Specifically, I don't know how to construct the SQL query inside the `cursor.execute` to account for different scenarios (the user may just want to retrieve trade information by share_id, or by both broker_id and date_range).

*PS: date range should include from_date and to_date of transaction_time.*

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the inputs provided by user with a case statement with an escape clause (else part of case here) corresponding to the no input situation. This way you can handle more than one inputs independently. In this case, no input is mapped to input variable being null (not a default non-null value). You should be able to extend this to include date range inputs also.

Try

```
share_id_val = input("Enter share id to search: ")
broker_id_val = input("Enter broker id to search: ")

cursor.execute("
SELECT * FROM trades WHERE 1=1
and share_id = case when :share_id_bind_var is not null then :share_id_bind_var else share_id end
and broker_id = case when :broker_id_bind_var is not null then :broker_id_bind_var else broker_id end
", 
share_id_bind_var = share_id_val,
broker_id_bind_var = broker_id_val
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Just wondering what does the `WHERE 1=1` do?

Comment: 1=1 does nothing.. but its easy to debug sometimes by changing this to 1=0 ensuring that this sql statement does nothing. If you have a lot of sqlS and you want to test/debug 7th out of 15 in a function... use 1=0 for sqls #1 to 6 and so on.. Of course it depends on dependencies, if 7 depends on 2 but not the rest then sql #2 has 1=1 and others have 1=0 etc..